# Device location in LTE/GSM packets?

Tags: sniffer, gsm, 4g

I'd like to know if any of the LTE or GSM packets have the GPS coordinates of a given device or any information about its geolocation. I mean, there must be a way to locate devices (maybe triangulation from 3 base stations) so I wonder if this information goes in any of the packets in LTE or GSM.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see a relation to information **security**. A better site to ask question about 
 lower level protocols might be [networkengineering.se].

Comment: ok, thank you. When I was researching for this, question on the topic came out on this forum. but I'll move it to the other forum anyway :) oh! and believe: this is FOR information security applications ;)

Comment: Not everything which is used FOR information security is ABOUT information security. You probably need an operating system to run your information security programs - but setup of this system and similar questions are still not about information security.